# Can I use a LINQ IEnumerable result as the data source for a Gtk.TreeView?

Tags: c#, linq, mono, gtk#

When using GTK# from C# on Mono, I often find myself copying out C# data structures into Gtk.ListStore -- it would be much easier if there was a Gtk.TreeModel which wrapped an IEnumerable.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played with GTK# for a long time but iirc GTK# lacks the databinding features that MWF and ASP.Net have. You could implement your own wrappers/helpers. I also found this http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Mar-26-1.html that might be of help to you. According to the post it should extend GTK# to allow for databinding to datasources like IEnumerable lists.